# Why does my model have black lines on the mesh when I zoom out?

Tags: mesh, materials, uv, shaders

I have no idea why this happens and I am really stressed out about it. Can someone please help me?

Close: No Problem.
[image]

Far: Black line left of eye where my UV seam was...
[image]

Comment: maybe it's a preview artefact, because of the UV? If the render is ok I guess you don't have to care?

Comment: not necessarily, because i design assets for games. They have this problem when they are in Unity as well.

Comment: How does the UV map looks like in the UV/Image Editor?